# Plotting multiple dataframes from multiple csv files into one plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

i have several sensor measurements saved in several csv files. I want to compare the values in one single plot, but i cant make this work. I always end up open every graph into an own plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

daten = pd.read_csv("testX.csv")
datenZwei = pd.read_csv("testY.csv")
datenDrei = pd.read_csv("testZ.csv")

daten.plot(kind='line', x=' X', y=' Y1 (SX (N/m^2))')
datenZwei.plot(kind='line', x=' X', y=' Y1 (SY (N/m^2))')
datenDrei.plot(kind='line', x=' X', y=' Y1 (SZ (N/m^2))')

plt.show()
```

[image: This is the result, but i want them all to be in one figure]

This is the result, but i want them all to be in one figure, how can i do that?
Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 1):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x_value,y_value)
ax.plot(x2_value,y2_value)
```

substitute x and y values with correct entries on you dataframe

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating a figure with an axes object:
`fig, ax = plt.subplots()` and then passing that axes object to the "ax" argument of the pandas plot method:

```
daten.plot(kind='line', x=' X', y=' Y1 (SX (N/m^2))', ax= ax)
datenZwei.plot(kind='line', x=' X', y=' Y1 (SY (N/m^2))', ax= ax)
datenDrei.plot(kind='line', x=' X', y=' Y1 (SZ (N/m^2))', ax= ax)
```